# How to locate window that opens on clicking an element inside in the frame in the selenium -java

Tags: selenium

unable to locate the window that opens on clicking one element that is already inside the frame.for reference I checked the  source code , that window is inside the div tag with class as k-window k-widget.

Comment: Can you please share DOM or url ?

Comment: sorry that is organization specific , so I can't share